# Scraping aspx page using php curl

Tags: php, asp.net, curl, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape a aspx page using php curl code, which contains data page wise. Initially the page loads with get method, but as we select page no. from drop down it submits page the page using post method.

I want to find data of particular page no by passing postfields to curl, but couldn't do that.

I have created a dummy code to get records of 5th page, but it always returns result of first page.

Sample code

```
$url = 'http://www.ticketalternative.com/SitePages/Search.aspx?catid=All&pattern=Enter%20Artist%2c%20Team%2c%20or%20Venue';
$file=file_get_contents($url);
//<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value=
preg_match_all("#<input.*?name=\"__VIEWSTATE\".*?value=\"(.*?)\".*?>.*?<input.*?name=\"__EVENTVALIDATION\".*?value=\"(.*?)\".*?>#mis", $file, $arr_viewstate); 
$viewstate = urlencode($arr_viewstate[1][0]);
$eventvalidation = urlencode($arr_viewstate[2][0]); 
$options = array( 
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, // return web page
CURLOPT_HEADER => true, // don't return headers 
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true, // follow redirects 
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", // handle all encodings 
CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "spider", // who am i 
CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true, // set referer on redirect 
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120, // timeout on connect 
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 1120, // timeout on response 
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, // stop after 10 redirects 
CURLOPT_POST => true,
CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '__EVENTTARGET='.urlencode('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$SearchResults1$SearchResultsGrid$ctl13$ctl05').'&__EVENTARGUMENT='.urlencode('').'&__VIEWSTATE='.$viewstate.'&__EVENTVALIDATION='.$eventvalidation.'&__LASTFOCUS='.urlencode('').'&ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$SearchResults1$SearchResultsGrid$ctl13$ctl05=4');
$ch = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt_array($ch,$options);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

preg_match_all('/<a id=\".*?LinkToVenue\" href=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)<\/a>/ms',$result,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Can anybody help me out with this, where am I getting wrong, I think its not working because at first time page loads with GET method and as we go on page links it uses post.

How will I get records of particular page no.?

Regards

Comment: You may not be able to POST due to ASP.NET's ViewState validation. It's a ridiculous hash of all of the form values.

Comment: @jrummell - so what can be done to overcome this?

Comment: You would have to somehow recreate the ViewState hash based on your POST variables (and the ones on the page that you're not using). I have no idea how you would do that. Do you have access to the aspx source? Could you alter it to accept GET parameters instead?

Comment: No I don't have access to aspx source, its complete external link, but are you sure its because of ViewState??

Comment: Fairly certain, but I haven't seen the error you're getting, so I can't be sure.

Comment: I am not getting any error, it just returns scrap values of first page, I want results for other page too.

Comment: The key point is *validation*. What you are attempting to do is just like some attack code (even if that's not what you are doing). Imagine having a site that *blindly* accepts data POSTed to it from anywhere...I'm sure there are, but thankfully ASP.Net has this "ridiculous hash" that may not be perfect but at least protects a "developer" from him/herself in some rudimentary fashion...

Comment: @EdSF - The point of the VIEWSTATE parameter is to keep track of view state, not to protect against csrf attacks.

Comment: @pguardiario Yes, and it is signed [to protect from tampering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx#viewstate_topic12) by default.

Comment: @EdSF - You're confused. VIEWSTATE is not a csrf token. Csrf tokens are usually around 20 chars and are used to prevent a csrf attack. The VIEWSTATE parameter on the other hand is a 1k or so base64 encoded  inventory of all the junk on the page which is sometimes useful but mainly just clogs up internet tubes, so jrummell is correct to call it a ridiculous hash.

Comment: @pguardiario - Agreed, its not **meant** to be csrf, but at least protects from tampering rudimentary fashion. _" With ASP.NET view state, the LosFormatter performs a MAC by hashing the view state data being serialized, and appending this hash to the end of the view state."_

Comment: First, get the page via GET, then POST to the form url including all the input fields. Make sure you pass all the form fields, including VIEWSTATE.

Answer (score -3):

I write scrapers in php sometimes when a client requires it but I would never attempt to scrape an ASP.NET site with php. For that you need perl python or ruby. All 3 have a mechanize library that usually makes it easy.